# get Open website dialog

Tags: c#

My c# application need **URL** of local website running on **IIS**. I would like to have a dialog which prompts user with available local website like VS have(below image).

Is there a way to get that like `FolderBrowserDialog` in c#.

[image]

Comment: [This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx) describes how you can communicate with IIS server. You can create your own user control or dialog, depending on your needs. I don't know if there's anything built-in already.

Comment: That means there is no inbuilt facility for that. Thank for the reply.

Comment: I have never seen/found anything like that. Maybe there's (some open source, because I was not able to find anything on msdn). Personally, I'd create dialog that could communicate with IIS server. It will take less time than searching for this kind of dialog, IMO. +1 Interesting question, BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have searched for that hours. But did not find what I needed. :(

Answer (score 1):

For This You must make a custom Dialog box,this is not hard,first get list of web site in IIS directory using `System.DirectoryServices` namespace.and so on...

For More Information take a look at [C# - IIS: List Websites](http://cstruter.com/blog/306)